# Valid algorithm to calculate difference between two times?

Tags: android, time

I have a train schedule app, and I am trying to calculate the difference between two times with the following format HH:MM, so my users can easily see if the train is late (note: I am fetching the "real" data from the internet, so it is up-to-date). This is what I am doing at the moment:

```
    //schedule time of the train
    int hs=12;
    int ms=0;

    //real time of the train
    int hr=12;
    int mr=15;

    int t1=hs*60 + ms;
    int t2=hr*60 + mr;

    int d; //integer for the difference in minutes
    if(hr>=hs) d=t2-t1; //standard situation
    else d=1440+t2-t1; //for situation like sch: 23:55, real: 00:05
```

Is this correct? Am I forgetting anything? I had a few tries before this algorithm, all of them had minor bugs, which could confuse my users. As far as I see, this one does not have any glitch, at least I couldn't find any.

P.S.: I won't use any 3rd party libs, so I have to write my own algorithm, tho I hope it will be the final...

Thx!

EDIT: note: the values of hs/ms/hr/mr are hardcoded in this example, tho in my app, I have them updated correctly, for each row.

Comment: Date and Calendar are not third part library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you the minute difference on any day, or over the border of any day, except for daylight savings time.

Comment: well I won't really care about this, since daylight savings are changed when no train is on the move, so any search will just ignore this :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Java [Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) and [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) and [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) utility classes to achieve what you want (they are not 3rd party, they are java libraries and included into the Android SDK).

You have a great exemple for what you want here: [Is there a function to calculate the difference between two times and display a relative result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473735/is-there-a-function-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-and-display-a)

For the DateFormat class you have a good example here: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.text/formatdate.html

Comment: I'm going to check it, however I read somewhere, that theese parts of the libs are pretty broken, and ppl would suggest 3rd party libraries... I don't know, if they are right, but that is one thing why I would write my own solution. Thx anyway! :)

Comment: No they are not broken at all... Do you really believe that libraries used so much and part of default Java would be broken? They aren't and they are suited for what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: Well, I might be a bit too paranoid from times to times... :) Anyway, I wasn't sure if thoose rumours are true or not, even tho I suspected they aren't, I wanted to be sure.